# Как скрыть в allure report передаваемые параметры(password)? Python+Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Подскажите пожалуйста, я недавно в автотестировании, но столкнулся с следующим вопросом: allure report отображает password для используемых в тестах аккаунтов. Как можно скрыть передаваемые в запрос параметры?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему тесты в принципе не предназначены для того, чтобы пихать в них секретные данные вроде пароля

Comment: @andreymal, дело не в том что эти данные пихаются в тесты, как вы подумали. аллюр автоматом подхватывает все аргументы функции.

Comment: @ДанилМанмарёв таких аргументов в принципе не должно существовать во время выполнения тестов

Comment: В тестах нужно использовать специальные тест-аккаунты.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, способа скрыть какой-то отдельный аргумент нет.

Я могу предложить разве что одно очевидное и одно не очень красивое решение. (и я надеюсь кто-то подскажет вам что-то получше)

1. использовать `with allure.step(...)` внутри метода вместо декоратора `@allure.step(...)`, тогда в репорте не будет аргументов метода.
2. Вместо декоратора `@allure.step(...)` использовать кастомный декоратор, что-то вроде:

```
from functools import wraps
from allure_commons.utils import represent, func_parameters

import allure


def hidden_params_step(step_title):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            f_args = list(map(lambda x: represent(x), args))
            f_params = func_parameters(func, *args, **kwargs)
            with allure.step(step_title.format(*f_args , **f_params )):
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

я тестировал что-то подобное месяц назад, работало. Но я бы не назвал это решение правильным.